# Does Groovy allow generic object casting for abstract method attributes?

Tags: oop, inheritance, groovy

I want to force all Command objects that manage communicating Domain objects in the MVC to implement a setData method for their respective domain objects.

So, let's say it is given:

```
class User { //this is a domain
   Long id
   String userName
}
```

And base command:

```
abstract class DomainObjectCommand {
    ...

    abstract setData(Object domain)

    ...
}
```

And finally, the actual command object we will use:

```
class ListUserCommand extends DomainObjectCommand {

    Long userId
    String userName

    public setData( User user ) { //this is not a valid implementation of the abstract method because "Object" is not "User"
      ...
    }
}
```

Is there a *graceful* way to do this?

I want to be certain all command objects behave similarly in the way domain data is set in the command, but obviously each command will have its own unique domain object it must manage so the abstract method needs to allow for **any** domain object, not just User or Role or whatever it might be.

For now, I simply stopped the "enforcement" by implementing a base method and throwing a basic exception:

```
public setData(Object domain) {
    throw new NotImplementedException()
}
```

Comment: I've tried this using Interface and Abstract classes and neither works? An abstract base method with a typed Object being passed into a method must be of that type - unless I am mistaken? It seems there must be a way to allow a contract like this...

Comment: Apparently this is impossible. I'm shocked groovy doesn't allow this - it's so insanely flexible everywhere else. Can anyone explain why OO doesn't allow a def or Object as an arg in abstract method to be cast as a truly generic object? I can think of uses where this would be helpful, especially when you want to make other developers follow more strict standards...

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with generic types. The abstract class defines that a generic type is going to be used like this:

```
abstract class DomainObjectCommand<T> {
    ...

    abstract setData(T domain)

    ...
}
```

In the implementation class we define the actual type (In this case user).

```
public class ListUserCommand extends DomainObjectCommand<User> {
    Long userId
    String userName

    public setData( User user ) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!I was not aware of this concept - it works perfectly. :)

Comment: I can't upvote your response yet, I'll have to wait until I'm at 15. But I do appreciate your feedback.